# How to check if specific keys and values are also in a dictionary?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

The following is a subset of a nested dictionary that I have:

```
data = {
    '1': {'Address': '10/3 Beevers St',
       'Age': '27',
       'Job': 'Doctor',
       'Married': 'No',
       'Name': 'John',
       'Sex': 'Male',
       'Suburb': 'Marine'},
 '2': {'Address': '11/2 Sayers St',
       'Age': '22',
       'Job': 'Lawyer',
       'Married': 'Yes',
       'Name': 'Marie',
       'Sex': 'Female',
       'Suburb': 'Raffles'},
 '3': {'Address': '5/1 Swamphen St',
       'Age': '24',
       'Job': 'Manager',
       'Married': 'No',
       'Name': 'Luna',
       'Sex': 'Female',
       'Suburb': 'Eunos'},
 '4': {'Address': '25/12 Swamphen St',
       'Age': '35',
       'Job': 'Teacher',
       'Married': 'Yes',
       'Name': 'Larry',
       'Sex': 'Male',
       'Suburb': 'Eunos'}
}
```

And here is a JSON string:

```
json_str = '[{"Suburb": "Marine", "Address": "3 Beevers St"},\
             {"Suburb": "Raffles", "Address": "11/2 Sayers St"},\
             {"Suburb": "Eunos", "Address": "Swamphen St"}]'
```

My task is to check if a house (`"Suburb"` and `"Address"`) in `json_str` is also in the original dataset (nested dictionary called `data`). If it is, then add the key/value for `'Age'` and `'Name'` to the JSON string for that house.

The output looks something like this:

```
[{'Age': 27,
  'Address': '10/3 Beevers St',
  'Name': 'John',
  'Suburb': 'Marine'},
 {'Age': 22,
  'Address': '11/2 Sayers St',
  'Name': 'Marie',
  'Suburb': 'Raffles'}]
```

Thus, I was wondering if I can get some help on how to approach this question? I have tried writing out a code, but I keep getting errors, so I believe my approach is very incorrect...

```
def add_additional_info(data, json_str):

    python_dict = json.loads(json_str)
    new_dict = {}
    for some_id, sales_data in data.items():
        for houses in python_dict:
            if houses["Suburb"] == sales_data["Suburb"] and \
               houses["Address"] == sales_data["Address"]:
                new_dict[houses] = {'Age': sales_data['Age'],
                                    'Address': sales_data['Address'],
                                    'Name': sales_data['Name'],
                                    'Suburb': sales_data['Suburb']}
            else:
                new_dict.remove(houses)
    return new_dict.dumps
```

Comment: There are a number of errors with the formatting of the data in your question plus the code references some undefined things (such as `main_data` and `copied_dict`). Please fix all these things so your question contains a runnable [mre].

Comment: Hi @martineau, apologies, I've now fixed all the errors that I can spot. If there are any more, I would be grateful if you could let me know,

Comment: I think it's much improved now. There's still some (other) errors in the code part, but I'm not sure if they're part of what you are asking about or not — I'll assume they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you said you want, include the clarifications you mentioned in comments about ignoring duplicate matches and the specified ordering of the keys in the results.

First, the test data:

```
data = {
    '1': {'Address': '10/3 Beevers St',
       'Age': '27',
       'Job': 'Doctor',
       'Married': 'No',
       'Name': 'John',
       'Sex': 'Male',
       'Suburb': 'Marine'},
 '2': {'Address': '11/2 Sayers St',
       'Age': '22',
       'Job': 'Lawyer',
       'Married': 'Yes',
       'Name': 'Marie',
       'Sex': 'Female',
       'Suburb': 'Raffles'},
 '3': {'Address': '5/1 Swamphen St',
       'Age': '24',
       'Job': 'Manager',
       'Married': 'No',
       'Name': 'Luna',
       'Sex': 'Female',
       'Suburb': 'Eunos'},
 '4': {'Address': '25/12 Swamphen St',
       'Age': '35',
       'Job': 'Teacher',
       'Married': 'Yes',
       'Name': 'Larry',
       'Sex': 'Male',
       'Suburb': 'Eunos'}
}

json_str = '''[{"Suburb": "Marine", "Address": "3 Beevers St"},
               {"Suburb": "Raffles", "Address": "11/2 Sayers St"},
               {"Suburb": "Eunos", "Address": "Swamphen St"}]'''
```

The code:

```
SUBSET = 'Age', 'Address', 'Name', 'Suburb'  # Keys from data to put in result.


def add_additional_info(data, json_str):

    houses = json.loads(json_str)
    updated_houses = []

    for house in houses:
        # Search original dataset for house and add it to results, but only if
        # there's a single match.

        found = None
        for some_id, sales_data in data.items():
            if(house["Suburb"] == sales_data["Suburb"] and
               house["Address"] in sales_data["Address"]):  # Might ignore unit number.

                if not found:  # First match?
                    found = {key: sales_data[key] for key in SUBSET}
                else:
                    found = None  # Ignore multiple matches.
                    break  # Halt search for house.
        if found:
            updated_houses.append(found)

    return json.dumps(updated_houses, indent=4)


result = add_additional_info(data, json_str)
print(result)
```

Printed results:

```
[
    {
        "Age": "27",
        "Address": "10/3 Beevers St",
        "Name": "John",
        "Suburb": "Marine"
    },
    {
        "Age": "22",
        "Address": "11/2 Sayers St",
        "Name": "Marie",
        "Suburb": "Raffles"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you're doing it now is comparing the complete dict entry for the JSON data with the complete dict entry of the other data. This will never match as these have separate keys, so the dicts are by defenition different.

You need to compare exact keys for both dict entries, fe:

```py
if houses['Address'] == sales_data['Address'] and houses['Suburb'] == sales_data['Suburb']:
```

Also, never delete entries from a dict you are looping through. This leads to weird results. Create a new dict to which you add the ones you need to return, and add the matching entries to that.

Comment: Hi @Edo Akse, thank you very much for your advice! I've tried implementing them in my code which I edited above. I think it's looking better, but I'm still getting heaps of errors. Thus, I was hoping if you could provide more advice on other errors in my code if that's okay?

Comment: Update the original question with an **EDIT** section below the existing question  for followups (to keep the original question for posterity). Or post another question and comment here with the link. Which one to use would depend on the complexity of the followup :-)